# Batch audio converter for Linux that can convert from FLAC to AAC

Tags: linux, audio, media-converter, flac

I tried a few audio converters but they were **very limited**. For example I can't find one that converts to AAC 512kbps (from FLAC).

Does anyone know of a powerful Linux audio converter? As powerful as AVS for example?

The program "Audacity" (which is an audio manipulation program) is able to do this conversion and is really good regarding the plenty of options it has but The problem is that I have to do it file by file. I need to convert about a thousand files at once. If there's a way to make Audacity convert "in batch" then we'd have reached the goal.

Comment: Can you specify which features you need?

Comment: well I've mentioned that I need to convert FLAC to **512kbps AAC**. that's one feature to start with.

Comment: The audio conversion software is very simple. It has nothing to it but covering as much codecs and having as much options as possible. ... all programs I've tried so far are very far from good. I need a powerful program. ... meaning that it covers more codecs and has more options. (like trimming for example. but don't focus on that)

Comment: Ok, then your only feature is that converts from FLAC to AAC? Or you look for something else?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/):

- FLOSS
- Runs on Linux
- Can convert FLAC to 512kbps AAC (see http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AACEncodingGuide).
- Has many more codecs and options.

Comment: I'll take some time since apparently it has lots of GUIs

Comment: Yes FFmpeg is used by tons of programs and has many GUIs (which often don't give access to all FFmpeg's features).

Answer (score 1):

Using Fedora 21 you can convert FLAC to AAC (320k) like that:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flac -strict -2 -b:a 320k output.m4a
```

Feel free to use any encoding bitrate (512k or whatever, and YES, it's working!).

Be sure you have installed ffmpeg from rpmfusion repository.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [gnome-sound converter](http://soundconverter.org/)

> SoundConverter is the leading audio file converter for the GNOME
>   Desktop. It reads anything GStreamer can read (Ogg Vorbis, AAC, MP3,
>   FLAC, WAV, AVI, MPEG, MOV, M4A, AC3, DTS, ALAC, MPC, Shorten, APE,
>   SID, MOD, XM, S3M, etc...), and writes to Opus, Ogg Vorbis, FLAC, WAV,
>   AAC, and MP3 files, or use any GNOME Audio Profile.
>
> SoundConverter aims to be simple to use, and very fast. Thanks to its
>   multithreaded design, it will use as many cores as possible to speed
>   up the conversion. It can also extract the audio from videos.

To install in Ubuntu/Debian and other derivatives

```
sudo apt-get install soundconverter
```

[source code installation](https://launchpad.net/soundconverter/+download)

[image]

Comment: I tried that one and it's good but still very limited than AVS. **And by the way** its AAC output is limited to 320 kbps. I REALLY CAN'T FIND A LOGICAL EXPLANATION FOR THIS. ... Thanks for the suggestion anyways :)

Comment: Do you have any experience with mentioned tool?

Comment: Yeah i use it mostly in converting audio files